# Python - Best way to find data in a very large textfile (8GB)

Tags: python, text, data-science

I would like to scan a **8GB textfile** (it's a log file) to find specific words. These words are stored in a dataframe with over **3400 rows**.

I've tried the solution below, which avoids having to load the entire document:

```
with open(filename) as f:
for line in f:
    do_stuff(line)
```

However, this is taking a very long time to process. It takes over 2 minutes to scan the entire document for one word. Multiplying it with 3400 would take 113 hours to complete the script.

Is there anyway to improve this process?

Comment: Easy: make `do_stuff()` run faster. You need to show what you do in `do_stuff()` for people to be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

Create a *set* of the words: `words = set(column_of_words)`

Then do something like:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        words_in_line = set(line.split())
        matches = words & words_in_line #the intersection
        if len(matches) > 0:
            #do something with the matches
```

Whatever you do -- don't scan the same file 3400 times. Find a way to scan it just once.